# What the number after the period in a date format

Tags: sql, date

2022-10-05 10:20:52.657

What is the '.657' in this date?

Comment: That's .657 of a second, or "657 thousandths of a second".

Comment: That's not a date, it's a _timestamp_. (2022-10-05 is a date. 10:20:52.657 is a time.)

Answer (score 0):

The format is YYYY-MM-DD hh-mm-ss-msms

```
Y = year
M = month
D = day
h = hour
m = minute
s = second
ms = millisecond
```

Comment: The default timestamp precision is 6, which would give you micro seconds.

Comment: Default format of what? There is a tag "SQL" and nothing specific. and such format (the ISO) is modern compared SQL. In any case you should substitute `-` with `.` on last hyphen, if you are using ISO 8601. (and often the recommended format has a `T` instead of the space). So add more details on your answer (and which cases)